# How to show a function converges to 1

Tags: pr.probability, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, recurrences

Consider the following recurrence relation in two variables:
$$f(a, b) = \frac{a}{a+b} f(a-1,b)+ \frac{b}{a+b}f(a+1,b-1) $$
for positive integers $a$ and $b$,
with the boundary conditions $f(0,b)=0$ for integers $b>0$ and $f(a,0)=1$ for integers $a\ge0$.

I believe that $f(1,n)$ converges to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity. However I can't see how to prove it.

Numerically the convergence is slow.

@FedorPetrov's reformulation of the recurrence as a probability question is as follows (lightly edited). Consider an urn with $a$ White and $b$ Black balls. Take a random ball, eat it if it is White and recolor it White (returning to the urn) if it is Black. Then $f(a,b)$ is the probability that when the balls become of the same color, this color is White.

Comment: did a random walk question lead you to this recurrence? if so, can you state that problem (I just woke up and can't figure it out immediately)

Comment: Is it assumed here that $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, with $a\ge1$ and $b\ge1$ in the recurrence?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, that is right.

Comment: @mathworker21 let be an urn with $a$ White and $b$ Black balls. Take a random ball, eat it if it is White and recolor it White (returning to the urn) if it is Black. Then $f(a, b)$ is the probability that when the balls become of the same color, this color is White.

Comment: @FedorPetrov May I add your explanation to the question? It's very nice

Comment: @Simd sure you can. Was not it the origin?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think the recurrence originally came from a similar probability question.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Nice! I just came back to this and thought of a rabbit wanting to go on a walk but heading home when he (sometimes) sees a fox that is chasing him. Precisely, if home is at $0$, the rabbit at $a$, and the fox at $a+b$, then with probability $\frac{a}{a+b}$, the rabbit and the fox both move left, while with probability $\frac{b}{a+b}$, the rabbit moves right (and the fox stays still). Then $f(a,b)$ is the probability the fox captures the rabbit before the rabbit makes it (safe) back home. However, I like your interpretation better.

Comment: Also, someone who knows generating functions: what would be the right generating function to look at here? Would it be $F(x,y) := \sum_{m,n = 0}^\infty f(m,n)x^m y^n$, or do you look at some single-variable generating function?

Comment: @mathworker21 The series $\Phi(x,y):=\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{f(m,n)}nx^{m-1}y^n$ satisfies$$x^2(1-x)\Phi_x(x,y)+(x-y)y\Phi_y(x,y)+x(1-2x)\Phi(x,y)+y^2\Phi_y(0,y)=\frac{xy}{1-x}$$but I do not quite see how to use it

Comment: Zach Hunter's argument after all looks ok for me

Comment: The setup is from the "Pill problem" (AMM-problem E3429,(vol. 98(3) 1991, p.264) by Knuth and McCarthy)): 
A certain pill bottle contains m large pills and n small pills, where each large pill is equivalent to two small ones.  
Each day the patient chooses a pill at random, if a small pill is selected, (s)he eats it; otherwise (s)he breaks the selected pill and eats one half, 
replacing the other half, which is thenceforth considered to be a small pill.  --You'll find some literature using this keyword.

Comment: Following [esg's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460095/how-to-show-a-function-converges-to-1#comment1195054_460095), I found [A drug-induced random walk](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.04.299) by Daniel Velleman, *Amer. Math. Monthly* 121 (2014), 299-317.

Answer (score 6):

The urn problem is equivalent to a continuous-time process where the balls behave independently.

Balls can be either Black, White, or Gone. For each ball, there's an independent Poission process of events at some fixed rate (say, $\lambda = 1$). An event turns a Black ball into a White ball, and turns a White ball into a Gone ball (and turns a Gone ball into a Gone ball). Given an initial configuration of $a$ White and $b$ Black balls, what's the probability $f(a, b)$ that the balls are all White (or Gone) before they are all Black (or Gone)?

For each ball $i$, its history is characterized by the interval of time $(X_i, Y_i)$ that it spends in the White state. It is Black before that, and Gone afterwards. The times at which all balls are Black or Gone are the times outside the union of these intervals $(X_i, Y_i)$. They're all Gone at times that are *after* the union of these intervals. So an equivalent formulation of the question is:

**Q:** What's the probability $f(a,b)$ that the union of the intervals $(X_i, Y_i)$ is contiguous?

This formulation mostly agrees with the original one, except that it gives a different value for the case $a=0$. Because we said "contiguous" rather than "contiguous and includes 0", we have $f(0, b) = f(1, b-1)$ rather than $f(0, b) = 0$. So in this formulation we're interested in showing that $f(0, b) \to 1$ as $b \to \infty$.

We might hope that there are values $\varepsilon, M$ depending on $b$ for which, with high probability:

- (A) Each $(X_i, Y_i)$ intersects $(\varepsilon, M)$.
- (B) The union of $(X_i, Y_i)$ covers $(\varepsilon, M)$.

Roughly, for (A) we need $\varepsilon = b^{1/2} o(1)$, and $M > \log b + \omega(1)$. Guaranteeing (B) is a bit tricky. One might hope some interval just covers $(\varepsilon, M)$ with high probability, but AFAIK that's too ambitious. What we can do instead is find a third parameter $C$ for which, with high probability

- (A) Each $(X_i, Y_i)$ intersects $(\varepsilon, M)$.
- (B1) Some $(X_i, Y_i)$ covers $(\varepsilon, C)$, and
- (B2) Some $(X_i, Y_i)$ covers $(C, M)$.

A bit of experimentation gives values that work:

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon &= b^{-(1/2+\alpha)}
\\
C &= \log(b^{1/2 - \alpha - \gamma}) = (1/2 - \alpha - \gamma) \log b
\\
M &= \log(b \sqrt{\log b}) = \log b + 1/2 \log \log b,
\end{align*}

where $\alpha > 0$, $\gamma > 0$, and $\alpha + \gamma < 1/2.$

At this point it's a computation.

**(A) holds with high probability:**

Note that $X_i$ and $Z_i = Y_i - X_i$ are independent and exponentially distributed, so the joint distribution of $(X_i, Y_i)$ has density
$$\phi(x,y) = \exp(-x)\exp(-(y-x)) \mathbf1_{0 < x < y} = \exp(-y) \mathbf1_{0 < x < y}.$$

The probability that some $(X_i, Y_i)$ lies entirely to the left of $(\varepsilon, M)$ is at most

$$
b \,\mathbf P(Y_i <\varepsilon) = b \int_0^\varepsilon \int_x^\varepsilon \exp(-y)\ dy\ dx = b O(\epsilon^2) = O(b^{-2\alpha}) = o(1).
$$

The probability that some $(X_i, Y_i)$ lies entirely to the right of $(\varepsilon, M)$ is at most

$$
b \,\mathbf P(X_i < M) = b \int_M^\infty \int_x^\infty \exp(-y) \  dy\ dx = b \exp(-M) = 1/\sqrt{\log b} = o(1).
$$

So each $(X_i, Y_i)$ intersects $(\varepsilon, M)$ with probability $1 - o(1).$

**(B2) holds with high probability:**

For a fixed $i$, the probability that $(X_i,Y_i)$ covers $(C, M)$ is

$$
p = \mathbf P(X_i < C, Y_i > M) = \int_0^C\int_M^\infty \exp(-y) \  dy\ dx = C\exp(-M)
$$

Plugging in our values, this is

\begin{align*}
p =
C\exp(-M)
&= (1/2 - \alpha - \gamma) (\log b) b^{-1} (\log b)^{-1/2}
\\
&= b^{-1}(1/2 - \alpha - \gamma) \sqrt{\log b}
\\
&= b^{-1} \omega(1)
\end{align*}

(Here $\omega(1)$ denotes a term that goes to infinity as $b \to \infty$.) So the probability that **none** of the $(X_i, Y_i)$ cover $(C, M)$ is

$$
(1-p)^b = (1-\omega(1)/b)^b < \exp(-\omega(1)) = o(1),
$$

so one of those intervals covers $(C, M)$ with probability $1 - o(1)$.

**(B1) holds with high probability:**

As above, for a fixed $i$, the probability that $(X_i,Y_i)$ covers $(\varepsilon, C)$ is

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon \exp(-C)
&=
b^{-(1/2+\alpha)} b^{-1/2+\alpha+\gamma}
= b^{-1} b^{\gamma} = b^{-1} \omega(1)
\end{align*}

So one of those intervals covers $(\varepsilon, C)$ with probability $1-o(1)$.

In other words, with high probability:

- No ball turns White and disappears before $\varepsilon$
- Some ball turns White by time $\varepsilon$ and survives until time $C$.
- Some ball turns White by time $C$ and and survives until time $M$.
- No ball turns White after time $M$ (i.e. no balls are Black at time $M$.)

It follows that with high probability, there is no point after the first ball turns White that all the surviving balls are Black.

Comment: I also suspect there's a less-tedious argument in the continuous-time independent-balls formulation. (E.g. something in terms of an explicit formula for the distribution of the ball-states at time $t$, which can be handled with matrix exponentials?) Alas I haven't the time to look for a shorter answer.

Comment: Follow-up question: characterize which joint distributions of $X, Y$ have the property that sampling the distribution $n$ times and taking the union of the intervals $(X_i, Y_i)$ results in a contiguous interval with high probability as $n \to \infty$. Are there any nondegenerate cases where this isn't true?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, looking at $M = \log b + \log \log b$ and computing the probability that exactly one interval is stranded after $M$ gives you a bound $f(0, b) < 1 - (\log b)^{-1 + o(1)}$, so the probability goes to 1 fairly slowly.

Answer (score 5):

The following answer is incomplete.

Clearly, $0\le f\le1$. Let $h:=1-f$, so that $0\le h\le1$, $h(a,0)=0$, and $h(0,b)=1$ if $b\ge1$. Here and in what follows, $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers.

We want to show that $h(1,n)\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$). The idea is to construct a suitable majorant $g$ of $h$.

Let
$$g(a,b):=\frac{2 (1+a) b}{2 (1+a) b+a (1+a+b \ln b)}$$
if $b>0$, with $g(a,0):=0$.
It is enough to show that
$$h(a,b)\le g(a,b) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $a,b$.

Let us do this by induction on $m:=m(a,b):=a+2b$. If $m=0$, then \eqref{1} is trivial. Also, \eqref{1} turns into an equality if $a=0$ or $b=0$. If now $a\ge1$ and $b\ge1$, then \eqref{1} follows by induction from the given recurrence for $f$ (and the same recurrence for $h$) and the inequality
$$g(a,b)\ge\frac a{a+b}\, g(a-1,b)+ \frac b{a+b}\,g(a+1,b-1) \tag{2}\label{2} $$
for $a,b\ge1$. (To use the induction, note that $m(a-1,b)=m(a+1,b-1)=a+2b-1<m(a,b)$.)

---

**Remark:** Inequality \eqref{2} actually fails to hold, by a small amount of $\asymp10^{-13}$ for some very large $a,b$. I am leaving this answer for now, hoping that someone can modify $g$ a bit to make \eqref{2} hold.

Comment: Nice idea! However, I felt a bit lied to, with only the Remark at the end indicating you don't yet have a proof. I edited (as I see) appropriately.

Comment: @mathworker21 : Sorry if you "felt a bit lied to". That was not my intention. As soon as I discovered the mistake, I added the **Remark**, in boldface. That the remark is at the end of the answer is chronological. However, your edit is warranted and is now accepted.

Answer (score 4):

**Reduction:**

Fix $p\in (0,1/2)$. For large $n$, it is not hard to see that $$f(1,n)>f((p-4p^2) n,n)(1-3p).$$

Indeed, consider the balls an urn's setup of Fedor Petrov. For the first $pn$ steps, we have at most $pn$ white balls and at least $(1-p)n$ total balls, so we expect to eat at most $\frac{p}{1-p}pn<(2-\epsilon)p^2n$ white balls total (where $\epsilon>0$ since $p<1/2$). By a Chernoff bound, a.a.s. we should eat at most $2p^2n$ balls in the first $pn$ steps, and (assuming we run all these steps), we end up creating at least $(p-2p^2)n$ white balls.

Meanwhile, the probability that the original white ball is eaten in the first $pn$ steps is at most $(pn)\frac{1}{(1-p)n}\le 2p$. For large $n$, the a.a.s. event fails with probability at most $p$, thus a union bound gives that with probability $\ge 1-3p$, that at time $pn$ we have $\ge (p-4p^2)n$ white balls and $\le n$ black balls.

**Finishing touches:**

It remains to show that for fixed $c>0$ that $f(cn,n)=1-o(1)$. This follows from two observations (thanks to Fedor Petrov in the comments for clarifying my previous hand-wavy argument rigorous).

*Lemma 1:* $f(a,b)\ge a/(a+b)$ for all $a,b$.

Proof: This can either easily be deduced from the original functional definition of $f$, or otherwise can be derived from the probabilistic interpretation. Indeed, $f(a,b)$ is at least the probability that when we order all $a+b$ current balls according to what time they are drawn from the jar (which is distributed like a random permutation), that the last ball is white (since then all black balls are recolored before the white balls are consumed). QED.

*Lemma 2:* Fix an open interval $E\subset [0,1]$. There exists some $\epsilon,\delta>0$ so that for all $p \in E$, we have that $f((1-p)n,pn) \ge f((1-p)(1-\epsilon)n+\delta n-n^{2/3},p(1-\epsilon)n+n^{2/3})-o(1)$ (with the error term tending to zero as $n\to \infty$, uniformly in all choices $p$.

Proof: We shall determine $\epsilon,\delta$ a bit later.

We keep on taking steps until we have picked out $\epsilon n$ balls which were originally in the jar. By a Chernoff bound, asymptotically almost surely we eat at most $(1-p)\epsilon n +n^{2/3}$ of the original white balls, and recolor at least $p\epsilon n-n^{2/3}$ of the original black balls. Also, assuming that $\epsilon\le p/3$ we deterministically always have $\ge (2/3)pn$ original black balls (which haven't been recolored) and $\le (1/3)pn$ new white balls.

So (via more Chernoff bounds and some coupling), almost surely we eat $<(1/2+.0001)p\epsilon$ of our new white balls (since at each step we are at least twice as likely to recolor a black ball then eat a new white ball). Thus, we may take $\epsilon = \min(E)/3, \delta = .4999\epsilon \min(E)$. QED

Now fix some small $\eta>0$. By the original reduction, we have that $f(1,n)> f((\eta-4\eta^2)n,n))(1-3\eta)\ge f(\eta/2n,n)-3\eta$ assuming $\eta$ is small (recall $f(a,b)\le 1$ uniformly). To finish, we now claim that $f((\eta/2)n,n)> 1-2\eta$ for all large $n$ (whence $f(1,n) > 1-5\eta$ for all large $n$, so slowly having $\eta\downarrow 0$ gives $f(1,n)>1-o(1)$).

To verify this claim, we first note that $f((1-\eta)n',\eta n')\ge 1-\eta$ uniformly (by Lemma 1). Then we take $\epsilon, \delta$ from Lemma 2 applied to the interval $E = ((\eta/2)/(1+\eta/2),1-\eta)$, and note that the function $\phi:p\mapsto \frac{(1-p)(1-\epsilon)+\delta}{p(1-\epsilon)} -\frac{1-p}{p}$ is continuous and non-negative on $(0,1)$, thus there is some $c_0>0$ so that $\phi(p)>c_0$ for all $p\in E$ (we can take $c_0:= \delta/\epsilon\max(E)$). So, applying Lemma 2 a bunch of times ($\approx 1/c_0\eta$), we should be able to iteratively increment the ratio $(1-p)/p$ to find some $n'$ so that $f((\eta/2)n, n)\ge f((1-\eta)n',n')-\eta$. This completes the proof.

Comment: We have a uniform bound $f(a, b) \ge a/(a+b) $. For getting at least 99 percent of white balls we may partition the steps onto billion parts and apply Chernoff bound for each part, can not we?

Comment: okay yeah, $f(a,b)\ge a/(a+b)$ is easy. the main annoying thing with getting 99 percent is showing that we converge to 1 rather than some weird other solution (presumably you could show that the amount we increment at each stage is monotone, but that requires calculation). 


but doing a billion Chernoff bounds is what I want to do. I just don't have the know-how to make sure the differential equation that underlies things actually tends to 1 (though it surely ought to).

Comment: In your first display, $p$ cannot exceed $1/4$, because in that case $p-4p^2$ is negative.

Comment: If you have $n$ balls, the density of white is $p\in (10^{-9},1-10^{-2}]$ and you apply $10^{-9}n$ steps, the density seems to increase at least by $10^{-1000}$

Comment: if you want to avoid computations, then simply note that $((1-\epsilon) p+\epsilon q):((1-\epsilon) q)>p:q$, thus for every closed interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset (0,1)$ there exist $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$ such that if $p\in [\alpha,\beta]$ and you perform $\epsilon_1n$ steps, then the density $p$ increases at least by $\epsilon_2$ with probability $1-o(1)$. This suffices.

Comment: yeah but if $\epsilon_2$ shrunk exponentially with each iteration, you could be screwed. but really $\epsilon_2$ should be a decreasing function of $p$ (presumably). in which case, we always increase by $\epsilon_2(.99)$ until we get the desired ratio.

Comment: $\epsilon_2$ is a constant, what do you mean by shrunking exponentially? We remain in the same interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ only for finitely many steps, and when we leave it, the probability is already at least $\beta$.

Comment: oops I forgot it was over an interval, I thought you meant as a function to $p$. yeah that looks good.

Comment: @ZachHunter then I  suggest to rewrite the answer, as now it looks like incomplete, and my MO experience says that nobody reads the comments

Comment: @FedorPetrov I usually read all comments.

Comment: yeah I will rewrite in a day or so.

Comment: @ZachHunter Are you going to rewrite your answer?

Comment: ah sorry, I really should. I will set a reminder to do it tonight after work.

Comment: okay the lemmas are properly written. the conclusion is not the prettiest, but hopefully clear now.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using the so-called "fluid limit" for stochastic processes.

Consider $B_k, W_k$ the number of black (resp. white) balls at time $k$. Our aim is to obtain a macroscopic behaviour for these processes, in the limit $n \to +\infty$. For this, note that:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[B_{k+1} - B_k | \mathcal{F}_k] &= \dfrac{-B_k}{B_k + W_k} \\
\mathbb{E}[W_{k+1} - W_k | \mathcal{F}_k] &= \dfrac{B_k - W_k}{B_k + W_k}
\end{align}

In the same way that a biased random walk converges to a straight line at large scales, we can hope that this process has some deterministic limit once it is adequately rescaled. Indeed, this is the case: as $n \to +\infty$, uniformly over $t \in [0, 2 - \varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$,

$$(b_n(t), w_n(t)) =(\frac{B_{[nt]}}{n}, \frac{W_{[nt]}}{n}) \overset{\mathbb{P}, \|\cdot\|_{\infty}}{\longrightarrow} (b, w)$$

where

$$
b' = \dfrac{-b}{b+w},
w' = \dfrac{b-w}{b + w}
$$

and with initial conditions $b(0) = 1, w(0) = 0$.

Let us assume this result for now. Some elementary analysis shows that $b$ and $w$ both fall back down to $0$ at $t=2$, with $b'(2) = 0$ and $w'(2) = -1$. As a result, if $K > 0$ is large, we may pick $\varepsilon$ such that $\frac{w(2 - \varepsilon)}{b(2 - \varepsilon)} > K$: then, for large enough $n$, $\frac{W_{[n(2-\varepsilon)]}}{B_{[n(2 - \varepsilon)]}} > \frac{K}{2}$ w.h.p. It is then relatively clear that, with overwhelming probability, $B$ reaches $0$ before $W$ from this point, giving us the desired result.

We now just need to prove our functional convergence. We can start by decomposing $B_k$ into its predictable and martingale components:

$$B_k = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} \frac{-B_l}{B_l + W_l} + M_k$$

However, $M_k$ is quite small! Indeed, $|M_k - M_{k-1}| \leq 1$, so $\mathbb{E}[M_n^2] \leq n$ and, by Doob's maximal inequality, $\displaystyle\max_{0 \leq k \leq n} |M_k| \leq C_\eta \sqrt{n})$ with probability at least $1-\eta$. Thus, if $0 \leq t < 2 $, with probability $\geq 1-\eta$,

$$b_n(t) = \int_0^t \frac{-b_n(s)}{b_n(s) + w_n(s)} ds +\frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}}$$

and so

$$|b_n(t) - b(t)| \leq \frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}} + \int_0^t \frac{b(s)}{b(s) + w(s)} - \frac{b_n(s)}{b_n(s) + w_n(s)} ds$$

However, we can also see that $2b(s) + w(s) = 2-s$ (by taking the derivative) and $2 b_n(s) + w_n(s) = 2 - s + O(\frac{1}{n})$ (by recursion over $s = \frac{k}{n}$). As a result,

$$|b_n(t) - b(t)| \leq \frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}} + \int_0^t \frac{|b_n(s) - b(s)|}{1-\frac{s}{2}} ds$$

Similarly, with probability $\geq 1-\eta$,

$$|w_n(t) - w(t)| \leq \frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}} + \int_0^t 2\frac{|w_n(s) - w(s)|}{1-\frac{s}{2}} ds$$

By Gronwall's lemma, we therefore obtain that w.h.p.

$$|b_n(t) - b(t)| \leq \frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}(2-t)^2}; |w_n(t) - w(t)| \leq \frac{C_\eta}{\sqrt{n}(2-t)^4}$$

showing that $(b_n, w_n) \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\longrightarrow} (b, w)$, uniformly over $[0, 2-\varepsilon]$ for any given $\varepsilon$.

Edit: a few extra points:

- the proof as i wrote it is not actually complete, since I did not prove that $w_n(t)$ did not hit $0$ for $t$ close to $0$. However, it is easy to see that w.h.p $W_k > 0$ for $0 < k < \varepsilon n$, which is sufficient: Gronwall's inequality then says that $W_k > 0$ for $\varepsilon n < k < (2 - \varepsilon) n$.
- since $b_n$ is decreasing, the convergence is actually uniform over $[0, 2]$.

Answer (score 2):

I will use the probabilistic interpretation in my proof.

First, note that $P(1, n-1) = P(0,n)$ so we can reformulate the problem as follows:

"We start with a hat with $n$ black balls. When we take out a black ball, we paint it white and return it. When we take out a white ball, we leave it outside. We stop when we have only one ball in the hat. What is the probability that it is white?"

One issue with this formulation is that the process can take either $2n-2$ or $2n-1$ steps, so we will instead continue until there are no balls in the hat left, which will always take $2n$ steps. In this interpretation, the last ball is black if it was pulled twice in the last two steps.

If we label the balls as $b_1, \cdots, b_n$, all the possible outcomes are described by words of length $2n$ in which all $b_i$s appear twice. All these outcomes are equally likely, so we can find $1-P(0,n)$ as follows:

There are $f_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$ outcomes in total. Out of these, there are precisely $nf_{n-1}$ outcomes which have end in $b_ib_i$ for some $i$. This means that $$1-P(0,n)=nf_{n-1}/f_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}\implies\\ \implies P(1,n)=P(0,n+1)=1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$

Update: thanks to the comments, I have realised that I was solving the problem with a different boundary condition. Even then, this solution is actually wrong, because individual outcomes aren't equally likely.

Comment: No, we stop when they all become of the same color